# character and array

Tags: c++

I came across something unfamiliar in C++

```
char name[5] = "best";
```

I only know that char gives us a size of 1 character only.
So does the above line of code i.e. using arrays with char helps to increase the size of char data type ?
I hope now my question is clear.

Comment: A compiler allocates 5 bytes and initializes them with `something`. If `something` is too long, then there will be an compiler error or a warning.

Comment: ***I am currently learning C++ from youtube tutorials*** My advice is to get a book. This should be in a very early chapter in a c++ book. Although this is more c than c++. In c++ we would limit are usage of char arrays and prefer std::string.

Comment: guys m new to this  sorry for the mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char name;
```

This gives you a single `char` object.

```
char name[5];
```

This gives you 5 `char` objects, one after the other - this is called an array of 5 `char`s. You can index them with `name[0]`, `name[1]`... until `name[4]`.

```
"best"
```

This is a string literal. It represents an array of 5 `char`s in read-only memory, containing the characters `b`, `e`, `s`, `t`, and `\0`.

```
char name[5] = "best";
```

This declares an array of 5 `char`s, as before, and initialises each of the elements of that array with the elements of the string literal. The `name` array will now also contain the characters `b`, `e`, `s`, `t`, and `\0`.

Comment: Thanx joseph, i got the explanantion right !